# Fire a client when you have a part of responsibility for delaying project

Tags: difficult-client

I work on a project for a client . the project supposed to be delivered in 3 months for a fixed price . It's  a year since we have started the project and it is not finished yet . the responsibility  for this delay is on both of us , They were asking for a lot of changes and i sometimes was delaying delivering some work .

but i am sick of this project and it grows with time and i don't really want to work on it anymore even if they doubled the price we are agreed on .

How to fire the client in this situation ? since i have a part of responsibility in delaying some aspects of the project.

note : i don't have a contract.

Comment: Why do you use the term "firing".  It's normal for consultants to give notice oftentimes and move on.  Why can't you give some notice like you would with a real job?  I suggest an [edit] to your post to clarify.  Thank you and welcome to Freelancing SE!

Answer (score 1):

You fire an employee, you cancel/terminate/close a contract (verbal or written).

Avoid rocking the boat with the client - talk it thru with them, plan your exit strategy - they might well accept/understand and you never know, they too might be thinking fresh eyes might be the best way forward.

What country? I ask only because I am surprised that you could start a project without a contract - technically, you could walk away from it, your work could negatively impact their business, and they would have a tough fight to sue you for negligence.

Best of luck!